# Wordpress: invoke function in a page / post

Tags: php, wordpress, function, include

I rephrase my question in this new post to which I have not had any answer. These two functions create a page on the user's account endpoint. A table is published on this page. I would like this table to be published in a new page / post of the site accessible to all. Any suggestions? Thank you

1            `add_action( 'init', array(__CLASS__, 'wsc_add_my_account_endpoint') );`

2 `public static function wsc_add_my_account_endpoint() { add_rewrite_endpoint( 'wsc-share-cart', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES ); }`

3 The content that I would to print in a wordpress page:

````
            if ( !isset($_GET['wc-wsc']) || !isset($_GET['nounce']) ) {
                return;
            }
            if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( wc_clean($_GET['nounce']), 'wsc_save_share_cart' ) ) {
                return;
            }
            $posted_fields = wc_clean($_POST);
            $fields = get_option('wsc_form_fields');
            $errors = array();
            $form_submission = array();
            $form_submission_html = '';
            $customer_email = '';
            if ( !empty($fields) ) {
                $form_submission_html .= '<table>';
                foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
                    if ( true == $field['required'] && empty($posted_fields['wsc_form_field_' . esc_attr($key)]) ) {
                        $errors['wsc_form_field_' . esc_attr($key)] = wp_sprintf( '%s %s', esc_html__($field['label'], 'wc-wsc'), esc_html__('is required.', 'wc-wsc') );
                    }
                    $label = !empty($field['label']) ? $field['label'] : 'wsc_form_field_' . esc_attr($key);
                    $field_value = wc_clean($posted_fields['wsc_form_field_' . esc_attr($key)]);
                    if ( 'email' == $field['type'] ) {
                        if ( !is_email($field_value) ) {
                            $errors['wsc_form_field_' . esc_attr($key)] = wp_sprintf( '%s %s', esc_html__($field['label'], 'wc-wsc'), esc_html__('must be an email.', 'wc-wsc') );
                        }
                        $customer_email = $field_value;
                    }
                    if ( isset($posted_fields['wsc_form_field_' . esc_attr($key)]) ) {
                        $form_submission[$label] = $field_value;
                    }
                    $form_submission_html .= '<tr><th>' . esc_html($label) . '</th><td>' . esc_html($field_value) . '</td></tr>';
                }
                $form_submission_html .= '</table>';
            } ```
````

Comment: The code snippet you have shown appears to process data that has been POSTed with the current request. We can not tell from this, what happens with the created HTML afterwards - whether it just gets output directly, or stored somewhere. The latter would of course be the first prerequisite for you to be able to show this to _all_ users, outside of the scope of the current user's current request.

Comment: Can I send to you the whole code?

Comment: No. This is a place for public discussions, not one to solicit private support. Analyzing how the plugin currently works and what it does with the data, would be your responsibility here to begin with. If that is beyond your current abilities - then this rather doesn't belong here in the first place, it would be considered too broad of a question to be handled here. Consider hiring a developer then, or ask the plugin provider for support.